# Cannot shut down on 13.10 and 14.04

Tags: 13.10, shutdown, 14.04

13.10 has been re-installed on my i3. I cannot shut down or log out. The power button menu does not help and `sudo shutdown -h` now also did not help. Can you advise? Other suggestions to my query have been tried. I am still unable to log out or shut down.

Computer spec:

CPU: `Intel® Core™ i3-4130 CPU @ 3.40GHz × 4 ; Intel® Haswell.`
Motherboard: `Intel Round Lake dh87rl Lga1150`

If I select and click on Shut Down and hold down the power button for a count of 10, the machine will power off.

I have pressed F2 to Enter Setup when the machine reboots. Nothing happens. F7 to Enter Bios also does nothing. F10 to Enter Boot Menu made the PC freeze. I had to force a shutdown.

Sudo shutdown -h produced following message. The link is on Imgur: imgur.com/ud9ECnA

I Upgraded from 13.10 to 14.04 on 21 April 2014. The machine still does not shut down. I have to hold down the power button or 14.04 automatically reboots. 
My kernel is 3.13.0 -24-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Thu April 10 19:11:08 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU Linux

sudo shutdown -P now or sudo poweroff and sudo shutdown -h now do not help. Halt -p produces:"halt: Need to be root." sudo halt makes the machine freeze. sudo halt -p does not help. The machine reboots immediately.

I did not know how to enter Bios. Wakeup on Lan is disabled. The problem is solved.

Comment: did you tried `sudo shutdown -P now` or `sudo poweroff`?

Comment: These did not help. The machine automatically restarted.

Comment: What happens when you try those commands? Do you get any output?

Comment: What is your motherboard, and did you change anything in grub before having this problem.

Comment: Intel® Core™ i3-4130 CPU @ 3.40GHz × 4 ; Intel® Haswell. The PC is new. The previous 13.10 was an Upgrade from 13.04. This 13.10 was a complete reinstallation from a disc.

Comment: Intel Round Lake dh87rl Lga1150
Mtherboard

Comment: @guntbert have added comment.

Comment: Still reproducible?

Comment: @Braiam I do not understand question.

Comment: I see that you are still affected by this issue. You say that `sudo shutdown -h` does not help, how about `sudo poweroff`? Also, does it get some error?

Comment: sudo shutdown -h produces in link http://imgur.com/ud9ECnA

Comment: sudo poweroff does not help. The OS shuts down and immediately reboots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `shutdown` command does not work if wake on lan is enabled in the bios (see https://communities.intel.com/thread/45667).

If you have to use wake on lan use `halt -p` instead of `shutdown`.

Comment: halt -p does not shut down. If I press F7 to Enter Bios does this not do anything.

Comment: I did not know how to enter Bios. Lan is disabled. The problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

### Shut Down:

```
sudo shutdown -h now
```

or

```
sudo halt
```

or

```
sudo halt -p
```

### Restart:

```
sudo reboot
```

Comment: The Shut Down attempts failed. In each case the PC automatically restarted. On sudo halt the machine froze. R E I S U B and alt/ printscreen failed and I pulled the plug out...

Answer (score 0):

To shutdown I use the brother of reboot:

```
sudo poweroff
```

Comment: did you see the comments [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/418745/cannot-shut-down-on-13-10#comment539866_418745) and [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/418745/cannot-shut-down-on-13-10#comment540426_418745)?

Comment: sorry. I missed that. Anyway... didn´t you saw any message in the terminal after the command? any error or complain from the command to use it as a clue? after a poweroff your pc reboots??? are you sure?

Comment: @AvinashRaj I lost the thread of the help-discussion. I re-entered sudo poweroff, sudo shutdown -P now, sudo shutdown -h now. The machine shut down immediately and rebooted immediately each time. Before 'sudo shutdown-h now' the following appeared in the terminal: "$ down vote accept No command 'down' found, did you mean: command 'cdown' from package 'cdtool' (universe) down: command not found $ shut down: shut: command not found."