# Ubuntu 14.04 keeps restarting the PC

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, shutdown, intel, restart

When using Ubuntu 14.04, my PC doesn't shutdown.

When I try to turn it off, it performs the procedure, the led goes out.

Soon after it (re)start again.

That doesn't happen with Fedora 20 and Windows 8.1.

How to fix it?

Specs:

- mobo: Gigabyte Z87-D3HP
- GPU: Nvidia GeForce GTX 660
- CPU: Intel i7 4770

The solution found in: "[Cannot shut down on 13.10 and 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/418745/cannot-shut-down-on-13-10-and-14-04)" didn't solve the problem.

Comment: My ubuntu happily shuts down when I run the command sudo shutdown now

Comment: my ubuntu didn't.

Comment: Welcome to AU! Can you provide the output of `cat /sys/power/disk` please? You can [edit] your question to improve it with more info.

Comment: Thanks! This output is: [platform] shutdown reboot suspend

Answer (score 0):

I followed some threads and changed /etc/default/grub file to reflect the following:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

Change to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=force"
```

Don't forget to run sudo update-grub afterwards to commit the new configuration.

Comment: Don't forget to run `sudo update-grub` afterwards to commit the new configuration.